# Cannot Scrape HTML Tag Using BeautifulSoup, Throws a NoneType

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have this script that is supposed to scrape some HTML here: https://pastebin.com/xvRBLjzb

For some reason, It can parse all elements with the " more-detail-content " but when I try to extract the " more-label " content, it throws a nonetype.

```
htmlbs = BeautifulSoup(htmlTag, 'html5lib').findAll('div', {'class': 'more-detail-content'})
for i in htmlbs:
    print(i)
    tempLabel = BeautifulSoup(i, 'html5lib').find('h4', {'class': 'more-label'})  #Prints NoneType
    tempVal = BeautifulSoup(i, 'html5lib').find('h4', {'class': 'more-value'}) #Prints NoneType
    print(tempVal)
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use one instance of `soup` and get the values with `find_all()`?

For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

htmlTag = '''
<div class="more-detail-Row"><h3 class="more-detail-head">General</h3><div class="more-detail-content"><h4 class="more-label">Band Color</h4><h4 class="more-value">Black</h4></div></div><div class="more-detail-Row"><h3 class="more-detail-head">Information</h3><div class="more-detail-content"><h4 class="more-label">Brand</h4><h4 class="more-value">Milus</h4></div><div class="more-detail-content"><h4 class="more-label">Series</h4><h4 class="more-value">Snow Star Heritage</h4></div><div class="more-detail-content"><h4 class="more-label">Gender</h4><h4 class="more-value">Men's</h4></div><div class="more-detail-content"><h4 class="more-label">Model</h4><h4 class="more-value">HKIT001</h4></div><div class="more-detail-content"><h4 class="more-label">Watch Label</h4><h4 class="more-value">Swiss Made</h4></div><div class="more-detail-content"><h4 class="more-label">Movement</h4><h4 class="more-value">Automatic</h4></div><div class="more-detail-content"><h4 class="more-label">Engine</h4><h4 class="more-value">Sellita Caliber SW200</h4></div><div class="more-detail-content"><h4 class="more-label">Power Reserve</h4><h4 class="more-value">38 hours</h4></div></div><div class="more-detail-Row"><h3 class="more-detail-head">Case</h3><div class="more-detail-content"><h4 class="more-label">Case Size</h4><h4 class="more-value">40 mm</h4></div><div class="more-detail-content"><h4 class="more-label">Case Thickness</h4><h4 class="more-value">10 mm</h4></div><div class="more-detail-content"><h4 class="more-label">Case Material</h4><h4 class="more-value">Stainless Steel</h4></div><div class="more-detail-content"><h4 class="more-label">Case Shape</h4><h4 class="more-value">Round</h4></div><div class="more-detail-content"><h4 class="more-label">Case Back</h4><h4 class="more-value">Solid</h4></div></div><div class="more-detail-Row"><h3 class="more-detail-head">Band</h3><div class="more-detail-content"><h4 class="more-label">Band Material</h4><h4 class="more-value">Leather</h4></div><div class="more-detail-content"><h4 class="more-label">Band Type</h4><h4 class="more-value">Strap</h4></div><div class="more-detail-content"><h4 class="more-label">Band Color</h4><h4 class="more-value">Black</h4></div><div class="more-detail-content"><h4 class="more-label">Band Width</h4><h4 class="more-value">20 mm</h4></div><div class="more-detail-content"><h4 class="more-label">Clasp</h4><h4 class="more-value">Tang</h4></div></div><div class="more-detail-Row"><h3 class="more-detail-head">Dial</h3><div class="more-detail-content"><h4 class="more-label">Dial Color</h4><h4 class="more-value">Silver</h4></div><div class="more-detail-content"><h4 class="more-label">Type</h4><h4 class="more-value">Analog</h4></div><div class="more-detail-content"><h4 class="more-label">Crystal</h4><h4 class="more-value">Scratch Resistant Sapphire</h4></div><div class="more-detail-content"><h4 class="more-label">Hands</h4><h4 class="more-value">Silver-tone Dauphine-style</h4></div><div class="more-detail-content"><h4 class="more-label">Dial Markers</h4><h4 class="more-value">Index</h4></div><div class="more-detail-content"><h4 class="more-label">Bezel</h4><h4 class="more-value">Fixed</h4></div><div class="more-detail-content"><h4 class="more-label">Bezel Color</h4><h4 class="more-value">Silver-tone</h4></div><div class="more-detail-content"><h4 class="more-label">Bezel Material</h4><h4 class="more-value">Stainless Steel</h4></div></div><div class="more-detail-Row"><h3 class="more-detail-head">Features</h3><div class="more-detail-content"><h4 class="more-label">Water Resistance</h4><h4 class="more-value">30 meters / 100 feet</h4></div><div class="more-detail-content"><h4 class="more-label">Calendar</h4><h4 class="more-value">Date display at the 3 o'clock position</h4></div><div class="more-detail-content"><h4 class="more-label">Functions</h4><h4 class="more-value">Date, Hour, Minute, Second</h4></div><div class="more-detail-content"><h4 class="more-label">Features</h4><h4 class="more-value">Analog, Compass, Leather, Stainless Steel</h4></div></div><div class="more-detail-Row"><h3 class="more-detail-head">Additional Info</h3><div class="more-detail-content"><h4 class="more-label">Style</h4><h4 class="more-value">Casual</h4></div><div class="more-detail-content"><h4 class="more-label">Warranty</h4><h4 class="more-value">2 Year Jomashop Warranty</h4></div><div class="more-detail-content"><h4 class="more-label">Additional Info</h4><h4 class="more-value">The extra cufflinks (16.6 mm) are made of stainless steel, and each one features a compass.</h4></div><div class="more-detail-content"><h4 class="more-label">Internal ID</h4><h4 class="more-value">MIL-HKIT001</h4></div><div class="more-detail-content"><h4 class="more-label">Department</h4><h4 class="more-value">Watches</h4></div><div class="more-detail-content"><h4 class="more-label">Category</h4><h4 class="more-value">Watches</h4></div></div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlTag, "html5lib")
labels = [l.getText() for l in soup.find_all("h4", {"class": "more-label"})]
temp_values = [t.getText() for t in soup.find_all("h4", {"class": "more-value"})]

print(labels)
print(temp_values)
```

This prints:

```
['Band Color', 'Brand', 'Series', 'Gender', 'Model', 'Watch Label', 'Movement', 'Engine', 'Power Reserve', 'Case Size', 'Case Thickness', 'Case Material', 'Case Shape', 'Case Back', 'Band Material', 'Band Type', 'Band Color', 'Band Width', 'Clasp', 'Dial Color', 'Type', 'Crystal', 'Hands', 'Dial Markers', 'Bezel', 'Bezel Color', 'Bezel Material', 'Water Resistance', 'Calendar', 'Functions', 'Features', 'Style', 'Warranty', 'Additional Info', 'Internal ID', 'Department', 'Category']
['Black', 'Milus', 'Snow Star Heritage', "Men's", 'HKIT001', 'Swiss Made', 'Automatic', 'Sellita Caliber SW200', '38 hours', '40 mm', '10 mm', 'Stainless Steel', 'Round', 'Solid', 'Leather', 'Strap', 'Black', '20 mm', 'Tang', 'Silver', 'Analog', 'Scratch Resistant Sapphire', 'Silver-tone Dauphine-style', 'Index', 'Fixed', 'Silver-tone', 'Stainless Steel', '30 meters / 100 feet', "Date display at the 3 o'clock position", 'Date, Hour, Minute, Second', 'Analog, Compass, Leather, Stainless Steel', 'Casual', '2 Year Jomashop Warranty', 'The extra cufflinks (16.6 mm) are made of stainless steel, and each one features a compass.', 'MIL-HKIT001', 'Watches', 'Watches']
```